# How to aggregate one column of django table based on another column

Tags: django

I have a table like below:

```
id    |    type   |    code
-------------------------------------

0.        5             2
1         6             6
2         8            16
3         4            11
4         5             4
5         2             2
6         4             1
7         10            6
8         9             2
```

All I need like output is a list of groupby on codes like here:

```
{ '2': [5,2,9], '6': [6, 10], '16': [8], '11':[4], ...}
```

I did this query but it's not doing the right query:

```
type_codes = [{ppd['code']:ppd['type_id']} for ppd in \
                    MyClass.objects \
                    .values('code', 'type_id')
                    .order_by()
               ]
```

Any help will be appericiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following, iterating over the query result (using `values_list`):

```
data = MyClass.objects..values_list('code', 'type_id')
res = {}
for code, type in data:
    res[code] = [type] if code not in res.keys() else res[code] + [type]
```

Comment: Thanks Marco for your answer. Your answer is correct, but I was wondering if django provides a straightforward solution for such a common query!?

Comment: Depends on your database. E.g. ArrayAgg for Postgres: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg